# flashcache tuning

Tags: cache, sysctl

I installed `flashcache` version 3.1.1 and created a write-back cache. The performance is good as long as the percentage of dirty blocks is not too high.

My application does heavy I/O at the beginning, and then calculates for a long time. So, `flashcache` has enough time to write the dirty blocks to the hdd but it writes the data at a very slow rate (2 MB/s). 
I tried to change that with `sysctl` but it didn't have any effect. How can I change the rate properly?

Here is my `sysctl` output.

```
$sysctl -a | grep flash
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.cache_all = 1
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.clean_on_read_miss = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.clean_on_write_miss = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.dirty_thresh_pct = 20
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.do_pid_expiry = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.do_sync = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.fallow_clean_speed = 100
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.fallow_delay = 600
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.fast_remove = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.io_latency_hist = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.lru_hot_pct = 75
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.lru_promote_thresh = 2
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.max_clean_ios_set = 40
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.max_clean_ios_total = 80
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.max_pids = 100
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.new_style_write_merge = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.pid_expiry_secs = 60
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.reclaim_policy = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.skip_seq_thresh_kb = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.stop_sync = 0
dev.flashcache.sda6+sdb9.zero_stats = 0
```

PS: My system is Debian testing.

Answer (score 1):

We have set up flashcache to write back aggressively. We see dirty block counts burst up to several tens of thousands, but it rapidly works its way down to a few thousand or even a few hundred once things calm down. Here are our settings:

```
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.cache_all=1
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.clean_on_read_miss=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.clean_on_write_miss=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.dirty_thresh_pct=10
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.do_pid_expiry=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.do_sync=1
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.fallow_clean_speed=100
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.fallow_delay=1
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.fast_remove=1
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.io_latency_hist=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.lru_hot_pct=75
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.lru_promote_thresh=2
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.max_clean_ios_set=300
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.max_clean_ios_total=2000
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.max_pids=100
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.new_style_write_merge=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.pid_expiry_secs=60
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.reclaim_policy=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.skip_seq_thresh_kb=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.stop_sync=0
dev.flashcache.sdb1+md0p3.zero_stats=0
```